# Does upgrading ubuntu versions update the software list?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

When the new Ubuntu version comes out on April 21, I am looking forward to update. However, many of the sources in my software list (e.g. wine, lutris, other general ppa sources) are set to impish. When I update to Jammy via software updater, will the sources be updated, or will I need to manually set them to Jammy?

Comment: Official Ubuntu repositories are changed to reflect the new release; but 3rd party software sources are **disabled**.  Third party packages can prevent upgrade, so some may need to be removed (eg. Oibaf graphics drivers often prevent *release-upgrade* from occurring, and need to be `ppa-purge` removed before upgrade can occur).

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Answer (score 5):

During ANY release-upgrade:

- **Ubuntu deb sources WILL be automatically changed** (renamed) to the new release.
- **PPA sources will be automatically disabled, not changed**. Many PPA sources are not ready on release day, so disabling the sources prevents "source not found" errors. Best practice is to review PPAs at release-upgrade time anyway: Many PPAs may be superseded by versions from another source.
- **Non-Ubuntu deb sources** (including wine and lutris) **WON'T be changed**. Like PPAs, review each source at release-upgrade time to see if you really still need that source.
- **Snaps should be unaffected**, since their updates are not related to the release of Ubuntu.

Keep in mind that PPAs and non-Ubuntu sources are generally not well tested by volunteers when preparing releases of Ubuntu -- more volunteers to do that testing are welcome! It's moderately common for PPA and non-Ubuntu software to block release-upgrades or cause partial upgrades (those are bad).

Best practices during any release-upgrade to have the highest likelihood of success is:

1. Backup your data before starting.
2. Return your Ubuntu system to as close to stock condition as possible. That means uninstalling all software from PPAs and non-Ubuntu deb sources. You don't need to uninstall packages from the Ubuntu repositories. You don't need to uninstall snaps.
3. Do the release-upgrade.
4. Review your PPAs and non-Ubuntu sources. You might want to start using software that is now available in the Ubuntu repositories or via snap instead. Check that PPAs have a version for the new release. Check that non-Ubuntu sources have been tested with the new release.
5. Reinstall PPA and non-Ubuntu software one source at a time, testing before moving to the next software.